# Emma Code Coverage Android not Updating

Tags: android, ant, junit, code-coverage, emma

After much trial and error I've got emma (code coverage tool) with ant for Android dev working purely on command line. Using Eclipse to try and run the test suite I get:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Which could possibly be part of the problem.

Any I've ran all the commands I've found such as

```
ant emma debug clean
ant emma debug
```

I use to run the test suite:

```
ant emma debug install test
```

**Problem**

However the report states that code is still untested even though I've written many new tests. IMO, I believe a new debug version isn't being complied, and I'm wondering if anyone has had similar problems. This could be due the the error I linked above, so currently I'm trying various remedies to resolve this first.

Many thanks

EDIT: could this be due to the generated build.xml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was the Robotium tests whilst working perfectly fine, were was it not to compile. To be honest I'm not entirely sure why but removing the tests using Robotium library worked.